# Design blocks, the right approach

Tags: adobe-xd

I create a training program for a sports project.
At the moment, the key colors on the site are:
52AFF8 31B7BD 3ECFC1

The training plan will look like, there will be three columns in it, the plan is 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on, the number that needs to be performed, the numbering of the approaches 3 2 3 4 2 and the icon of the plan is open or the icon is closed. The page will show 18 similar plans.

The question is:
Do I need a background for the frame, I take into account that there will be a lot of them on the page any color strongly catches the eye, and if you try the color that is on the site, it is not very beautiful.
What frame is better to make such or such[image]
[image]

I can use some kind of picture on the background, in general, I have a problem with creativity, I don’t know how to do it better, tell me how nice it is to make a block for a training plan, I'm just learning, I would be happy to look at examples.
At the moment I look like this, but I do not like it.[image]

Comment: I think it's a big difficult to make suggestions/critique anything without the entire picture. Your two boxes look fine to me, but an entire page may call for alterations for more visual separation at times.

Comment: @Scott [link](https://ibb.co/sqW87g0) At the moment it looks like this

Comment: I actually don't think that's bad. I would swap the background colors (#fffbfa for the page and #ffffff for the boxes so the boxes are "pushed" forward more).But I wouldn't add borders. Borders are going to make it appear *very* cluttered. All merely my *opinion* though.